# start() doesn't call run() method

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to run the following java program. But it is not showing any output.

```
    class Player implements Runnable{
        Thread t = new Thread();

        public Player(String name) {
            t.setName(name);
            t.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(t.getName() + "starts the race.");
        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(t.getName() + " crossed " + i + " obstacle.");
        }
        System.out.println(t.getName() + " finishes the race.");
    }
}

class Competition {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Player player1 = new Player("Cercei");
        Player player2 = new Player("Jamie");
        Player player3 = new Player("Tyrion");
    }
}
```

I have been imposed two constraints.

**1. Do not edit the Competition class.**

**2. You are not allowed to add any variables in the Player class. Only add necessary methods.**

the output might be like this:

> *Jamie starts the race.
> Cercei starts the race.
> Tyrion starts the race.
> Cercei crossed 0 obstacle.
> Jamie crossed 0 obstacle.
> Tyrion crossed 0 obstacle.
> Jamie crossed 1 obstacle.
> Jamie crossed 2 obstacle.
> Cercei crossed 1 obstacle.
> Cercei crossed 2 obstacle.
> Cercei finishes the race.
> Tyrion crossed 1 obstacle.
> Tyrion crossed 2 obstacle.
> Tyrion finishes the race.
> Jamie finishes the race.*

I have written the whole code as I have read about thread manipulation on the internet, but doesn't any output. Moreover, I've checked the debugger. after the `t.strat()` method, it never goes into `run() method`. Can you please help?

The original questions:

> Edit the Player class in the following code so that the code gives the expected output. Do not just print the
> expected output. Do not edit the Competition class. You are not allowed to add any variables in the Player class.
> Only add necessary methods. Will your code give exactly the same output as the expected output? Explain the
> reason.

```
class Player implements Runnable{
Thread t;
}
class Competition{
public static void main(String[] args){
Player player1 = new Player("Cercei");
Player player2 = new Player("Jamie");
Player player3 = new Player("Tyrion");
}
}
```

Comment: Hint - where do you believe you're telling the thread you're creating what it should do? How do you expect it to "know" about the `run()` method in your `Player` instance?

Comment: (And how much of that `Player` class was in the original question? You *do* have a variable in the `Player` class... was that in the original template? It's quite hard to know what those constraints mean without the original template.)

Comment: It really is not good practice to start threads in a constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've updated the question attaching the original question that I was asked. Can you please check. I am in new threading, I can not tell the answer to your hint. Can you please me to do this.

Comment: @AndyTurner then can you please tell me where I can start the thread inside the `Player` class? I have tried to make another method containing `t.start()` and calling it from the constructor, but the same result.

Comment: I would highly recommend you do some background reading on this topic as it's complex stuff and easy to make mistakes with. This tutorial by Jakob Jenkov is quite good: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html

Comment: @JonckvanderKogel Thanks a lot. I will check that. I am very new in `thread`ing, honestly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell the `Thread t` inside your class `Player` what is the target `Runnable` it should run.

Given your design, the target `Runnable` is the `Player` class itself (`this`):

```
class Player implements Runnable {
    Thread t;

    public Player(String name) {
        t = new Thread(this); //<-- the target Runnable of the Thread t is the instance of Player itself
        t.setName(name);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(t.getName() + "starts the race.");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(t.getName() + " crossed " + i + " obstacle.");
        }
        System.out.println(t.getName() + " finishes the race.");
    }
}
```

In your current code, you initialize the `Thread t` as `new Thread()` but you don't provide any `Runnable` to target, so the `.start()` method of the thread simply does nothing.

P.s. I strongly agree with Andy Turner's comment (even though I guess you're doing this just for exercise purposes): *It really is not good practice to start threads in a constructor.*

Comment: This worked! Thanks. Actually, I was newly learning to thread implementation and came to this problem. I didn't understand that a target must be provided with `Thread t`'s params. Thanks a bunch , again :)

Comment: One more thing, should I always provide `this` as the `Thread` objects parameter?

Comment: @ArifHamim you can imagine the Thread as a worker which is there to do something. That "something" is an implementation of `Runnable` that exposes a method `.run()` that should be provided to the `Thread`. In your case, the class `Player` implements `Runnable` so it's a good candidate. But no, it's not `this` that you need to pass (`this` simply means this instance), you need to pass an implementation of `Runnable` that in your case happens to be `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You just missing 1 parameter 'this' in `Thread` constructor

```
class Player implements Runnable
{
    Thread t = new Thread(this); // <-- here
  .
  .
  .
}
```